# What are some good resources for teaching end-users how to use WordPress?

Tags: customization

As a web designer and developer, I'd love to simply point out my clients to some YouTube videos or articles that explain from the ground up what WordPress is without blowing their mind.

Some of my clients are fairly well versed in internet, email and Word, but that's about their remit.

Does anyone know of some good tutorials, resources, articles or videos that are good to show my clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious place to start are the Wordpress sites themselves.

**For Authors**

For using Wordpress as an author I would recommend the support site:

http://en.support.wordpress.com/

I know this concerns the commercial, hosted, version of Wordpress, but the functionality is more or less the same. There's enough content here to get a beginner up and running with writing high quality content on a blog.

**For Developers**

For the more technically minded, the wordpress.org codex pages are fantastic:

http://codex.wordpress.org/

Specifically this one for getting started:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Getting_Started_with_WordPress

**Videos**

There's also wordpress.tv for those who want to watch videos:

http://wordpress.tv/

Although a lot of the content here is not tutorial based.

**Final comment**

I know this is all content developed by Wordpress, but if you're just getting started, there's no better place. The quality of the documentation provided by Automattic for Wordpress is actually the main reason I switched to Wordpress. I don't know a better documented web based publishing system. Open source or not.

Once you're a bit more clued up on things, sites like this one (wordpress.stackexchange.com) are very helpfull, as are the hundreds and thousands of blog posts that Google might return for a Wordpress search.

Answer (score 1):

I use [WP101](http://www.wp101.com/) as guide for my clients its not free but I include it in the price of the project.

> The WP101 video tutorial series is the fastest way to learn how to use
>   WordPress!

Comment: +1 for WP101. Shawn's videos are very well done and he even reshoots them to keep up to date with every major version change.